# Why does Docker FROM order matter?

Tags: .net, docker

Consider the following Dockerfile (from VS/.NET)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerIncluded/DockerIncluded.csproj", "DockerIncluded/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DockerIncluded/./DockerIncluded.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerIncluded"
RUN dotnet build "./DockerIncluded.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DockerIncluded.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerIncluded.dll"]
```

When working with it I noticed that the second FROM is not dependent on the base image, but the last FROM is dependent on the FROM before it. I wondered whether the file could look like this instead:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerIncluded/DockerIncluded.csproj", "DockerIncluded/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DockerIncluded/./DockerIncluded.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerIncluded"
RUN dotnet build "./DockerIncluded.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DockerIncluded.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerIncluded.dll"]
```

All I did was move the original first FROM to prelast, because it's not needed until that point. But when I run `docker run` on the built image, it can no longer connect to either 8080 or 8081. My guess is the base image is the image that exposes the internal container's ports for connection to the container orchestrator? Do I have it right?

Comment: The base image is indeed the one that exposes the final container's ports. Can you see any logs in the app when running ? Maybe you forgot to expose ports when using `docker run` ?

Comment: EXPOSE doesn't actually *do* anything. It's mostly documentation about what ports the image creator thinks the image uses. What matters is, like ABWassim says, what ports you map on your `docker run` command.

Comment: Whichever the visual studio uses internally. I am just trying to understand why ordering it differently matters.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio container tools has a feature called fast mode when debugging your project which optimizes the build. It actually uses VS to build your project, not your Dockerfile. In this mode, the Dockerfile is only used to determine the base container to inject the built app into.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#debugging:

> In Fast mode, Visual Studio calls docker build with an argument that tells Docker to build only the first stage in the Dockerfile (normally the base stage). You can change that by setting the MSBuild property, DockerfileFastModeStage, described at Container Tools MSBuild properties. Visual Studio handles the rest of the process without regard to the contents of the Dockerfile. So, when you modify your Dockerfile, such as to customize the container environment or install additional dependencies, you should put your modifications in the first stage. Any custom steps placed in the Dockerfile's build, publish, or final stages aren't executed.

You can override the name of the stage that it will use with the [`DockerfileFastModeStage` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022).